# How to release ImageResizer file handle?

Tags: c#, bitmap, imageresizer

I've been using ImageResizer for quite a long time but, today, I came across a problem I couldn't solve.

I use ImageResizer in a web project to show some thumbnails. The user can choose one of the picture by clicking the thumbnail, and then, should be able to edit the image (rotate).

ImageResizer is used just for the thumbnail, using the URL api (img.jpg?width=128). The rotation/image edition is done with GDI+ (System.Drawing.Bitmap RotateFlip).

If I just call the rotate method, and access the image URL (without calling ImageResizer), it works fine. I can call the rotate method as much as I want and I always get the expected result.

BUT, as soon as I access the ImageResizer URL API, the file is being use by ImageResizer and cannot be rotated anymore. When I try to save my bitmap image, and exception occurs: "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process".

Why is ImageResizer keeping an handle over the file ? How can I force it to release the file handle ?

Thanks by advance

**EDIT #1**

Here is the ImgRzr web.config related lines:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="resizer" type="ImageResizer.ResizerSection" />
    </configSections>

    <system.web>
        <httpModules>
            <add name="ImageResizingModule" type="ImageResizer.InterceptModule" />
        </httpModules>
    </system.web>


    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
            <add name="ImageResizingModule" type="ImageResizer.InterceptModule" />
        </modules>            
    </system.webServer>

    <resizer>
        <sizelimits imageWidth="0" imageHeight="0" totalWidth="6400" totalHeight="6400" totalBehavior="throwexception" />
        <remotereader signingKey="ag383ht2A162aCDe84fZ1pRfc2F5GhpB2twfqw" allowAllSignedRequests="true" allowRedirects="5">
        <allow domain="foobar.net" onlyWhenSigned="false" />
        <allow domain="localhost" onlyWhenSigned="false" />
        <allow domain="*.indev.be" onlyWhenSigned="false" />
        <!-- XML whitelisting requires V3.2 or higher -->
        <allow domain="*.foobar.net" onlyWhenSigned="false" />
        </remotereader>
        <plugins>
        <add name="RemoteReader" />
        <add name="DiskCache" />
        <add name="PdfRenderer" downloadNativeDependencies="true" />
        </plugins>
        <diskcache dir="~/Content/imagescache" />
    </resizer>
</configuration>
```

And here is the method used to rotate:

```
public JsonResult RotateImage(string imageName)
{
    string imagesPath = @"/Pictures/";
    string fullPath = Server.MapPath(imagesPath + imageName);
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(fullPath))
    {
        try
        {
            using (Bitmap image = new Bitmap(fullPath))
            {
                image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
                image.Save(fullPath + "new", image.RawFormat);
                image.Dispose();
            }
            // I tried this trick because saving directly on the image was throwing the file is use exception
            System.IO.File.Delete(fullPath);
            System.IO.File.Move(fullPath + "new", fullPath);

            /* I also trie to use ImageResizer but I've got the exact same error                
            ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.Current.Build(fullPath, fullPath, new ImageResizer.ResizeSettings("srotate=90"));
            */
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Log(ex);
            return Json("error");
        }
    }
    return Json("ok");
}
```

Now, let's say there is a picture named sample.jpg in the Pictures repository of my website. I can access it with www.foobar.net/Pictures/sample.jpg.
If I use the RotateImage("sample.jpg") method, the picture will be rotated. If I refresh www.foobar.net/Pictures/sample.jpg, it's different from the first time, the image has been transformed. Now, I call www.foobar.net/Pictures/sample.jpg?width=128 and I try to call the RotateImage("sample.jpg") again, the file in use exception will appear.

**EDIT #2**

I have been misleaded. I tried to setup a sample projet for you too see the problem but it's working fine. It's coming from somewhere else.

Comment: Some code would help us understand better.

Comment: Are you trying to overwrite an actively served image? 

ImageResizer writes result images to a cache folder, when configured with DiskCache. This ensure you won't run into file access issues. 

If you're handling I/O outside of ImageResizer, then we really won't be able to reason about your problem unless you post a repro project.